# Yammer's Experience w/ Scala

Tags: performance, scala, build-process, scalability, usability

I have been advocating using Scala at my company.  One of my co-workers forwarded me this link tonight

http://blog.joda.org/2011/11/real-life-scala-feedback-from-yammer.html

I was hoping to get some constructive feedback from the SO community about this.  I don't want this to turn into a flaming thread, but if there are legitimate concerns floating around out there I think it would be beneficial to discuss possible reasons and best practices that can avoid others falling into such traps.

I will say that I have been loving Scala and have not run into any of the problems that are mentioned.  My application is also not very hashmap intensive, which appears to be where a fair number of their problems came from.

[Edit - apparently I need a question!]

The question is, do you think that the problems described are systemic to Scala, or more unique to their environment?  If they are systemic, are there some good guidelines for a company that is just getting started with Scala to follow so that they don't end up in the same boat in 2 years?

Comment: And your question is...? SO is not a site for general discussion/feedback, regardless of how constructive it may be.

Comment: I added a question.  I have seen this style of question quite a bit on SO, I actually looking for information that can help me adopt scala in a smarter manner.

Comment: so this bloke Stephen has a recent history of going hard on scala for some reason :) he compared scala to ejb2 in one his blogs and then just could not justify the comparison. even in the article you mention, he's pretty abstract - i would love to see code samples and see why they could not be improved! one his blogs somebody even commented that he has literally no coding exp on scala. ignore him is what I would say. Scala is the coolest thing I have seen in the recent times.

Comment: [Should you use Scala? Is Java better? (You’re asking the wrong questions.)](http://codahale.com/the-rest-of-the-story/)

Answer (score 2):

### Issues Described

#### Language Complexity

Systemic issue. Scala is unlikely to get less complex, whether or not that is a ***problem*** depends on the developers that are working with it. For me, it is complex enough to keep me interested and engaged, whereas pure Java can be mind-numbingly boring. My suspicion is that if Scala is way too complex for a particular developer, it is unlikely they're going to be top-notch dev when it comes to Java as well.

#### Community

> So this one guy says the only way to do this is with a bijective map
>   on a semi-algebra, whatever the hell that is, and this other guy says
>   to use a library which doesn't have docs and didn't exist until last
>   week and that he wrote. The first guy and the second guy seem to hate
>   each other. What's the Scala way of sending an HTTP request to a
>   server?

That quote is pretty funny, but this is obviously a non-systemic issue with Scala. His main complaint about a lack of consensus regarding best-practices is relevant to all up-and-coming languages. I think Java developers have been spoiled in a way -- having gotten used to being part of such an enormous community where pretty much everything has been done before and possibly already standardized.

#### Build Toolchain

Another non-systemic issue.

#### Performance

This one does worry me a little bit and I can see getting frustrated very fast having to uncover previously unknown performance gotchas. I suspect for years to come there will be some pretty big performance penalties depending on how you use certain aspects of the language -- so people will have to exercise caution and make their own analysis regarding each project's performance requirements.

I concur with his sentiments here:

> Despite the fact that we're moving away from Scala, I still think it's
>   one of the most interesting, innovative, and exciting languages I've
>   used...

And finally I would urge people to read Stephen Colebourne's blog with some degree of skepticism, because his personal disdain for the Scala language seems a bit oversize relative to the arguments.

Comment: I find particularly distasteful that Stephen Colebourne is including the full content of the gist in his blog, emphasizing sentences of his choices - and misrepresenting it. It's basically a copyright violation. The original message is linked from http://codahale.com/the-rest-of-the-story/.